# How to Add a class in body on scroll using AMP Script in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried to add a class but not performing in a single post page on the blog.
I want to add class on scroll.
Simple jQuery and Using JavaScript that will add but using AMP Script they can be provided access to add it ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)